# Laravel 5 - URL Rewriting and CSS conflict

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, laravel, laravel-5

I have a problem in Laravel 5 between my .htaccess for the URL rewriting and my CSS files. First of all, here is my project tree:

[image: My project]

I have a .htaccess in my public folder as you can see on the picture. Here is the content of my .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
</IfModule>
```

This is the code I use to remove "index.php" in URLs. For example, `http://localhost/mySite/public/index.php/about` becomes `http://localhost/mySite/public/about`.

Now, I have a master page (in `/resources/views/`) and in this master page I would like to reference the css file which is located in `/public/css/style.css`. I added this code in my master page:

`<link rel='stylesheet' href="{{ URL::asset('css/style.css') }}" >`

This does not work with the current htaccess but if I comment the line `RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]` in my htaccess and access to the URL (with "index.php") the stylesheet is well referenced. I think I have to add an other line in htaccess but I have no idea what I have to add.

I hope you can help me and don't hesitate to ask for more details. Thanks.

Comment: Your reordering of the `.htaccess` rules has broken them. Understand them before changing. The two `RewriteCond` lines change the behaviour of the following `RewriteRule` - without one following them, they have no effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why did you change the [default .htaccess](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/public/.htaccess)?

It should be like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

The two `RewriteCond` prevent requests for files to be routed to Laravel. But they have to be *before* the `RewriteRule` to be effective.

Comment: `RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]` this is very hard,keep it as the original `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]`

Comment: @Gal I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: I don't know why but the default htaccess wasn't like this when I created the project. Anyways, thanks for the tip!

Comment: @lukasgeiter instead of `RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]` keep it as `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]`

Comment: @Gal First, I didn't write this. The code is straight from the Laravel repository and it has worked pretty well for me. Second the OP never had `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]` so *"keep"* is the wrong word.

Comment: @lukasgeiter well thats weired ,when I installed laravel I got it with `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]` any way I find it easier to read as the following regex request for any character -> redirect to index.php while the rule your using is searching for any kind of start/ending

Comment: @Gal That is indeed weird. Because the [file in the repo](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/develop/public/.htaccess) hasn't changed since 2013!

Comment: I don't know why but I generated a new project again and this time the line was there! 
I have a bonus question: is it possible to remove the /public in the URL? (I don't know if I should create a new question on stackoverflow)

Comment: @Moussamoa I suppose you somehow accidentally moved the line... The simplest way to remove the `public` in the URL is creating a virtual host and let the document root of that point directly to the `public` directory.